# How to replace www from the url in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I want to replace `www` from this url `"https://www.cmnetwork.co/courses/3684/redirect"`
with `newlife`.

I know using split we can do this. Is there any standard way of doing this?

Newly generated url should be:
`"https://newlife.cmnetwork.co/courses/3684/redirect"`

Comment: When asking a question like this we want to see an example of what you tried. Without that it looks like you didn't try. See "[ask]" and the links at the bottom of the page for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue that if you want to manipulate an URL then you should use a proper [URI class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) and not use methods on the URL string.

```
uri = URI('https://www.cmnetwork.co/courses/3684/redirect')
uri.host = 'newlife.cmnetwork.co'

uri.to_s 
#=> "https://newlife.cmnetwork.co/courses/3684/redirect"
```

It might feel like an overkill for this very simple example but it is IMO the better practice.

Comment: Most definitely using the accessors is better.

Answer (score -1):

Using `sub` method of ruby we can replace sub-string.

```
url = "https://www.cmnetwork.co/courses/3684/redirect"
url = url.sub('www.','newlife.')
```

Comment: In the OPs use this might work OK but I wouldn't do it in real life, especially if the incoming URLs were unknown. It'd break the URL if it looked like "mywww.foo.com". Either use Spickermann's solution or apply some additional logic. Also, `sub` takes a pattern so `/^www\./` would be smarter.

Answer (score -2):

try the following code to replace `www` from `url` eg.

```
url = "www.google.com"
url.gsub!('www.', 'app.')
```

Comment: `url = "www.foo_www_bar.com"`? This is very dangerous completely wrong approach.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin check my updated answer. Hope it works and save.

Comment: `url = "www.foo_www.bar.com"`?

Comment: `gsub` is dangerous in this case as it'll replace every occurrence of `www.` found in the string. `/^www\./` would be smarter, but `gsub` would still be overkill.